# как передать значение useState и props одному компоненту

Tags: reactjs

я новичок в React, я не понимаю как передать useState и props одному компоненту
вот код:

```
<PopupWithForm name="edit" id="Edit" title="Редактировать профиль" active={popActive} setActive={setPopActive}/>

function PopupWithForm({active, setActive},props){
...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const PopupWithForm = ({ active, setActive, name, id, title }) => {...}
```

или

```
const PopupWithForm = (props) => {
 const { active, setActive, name, id, title } = props;
...
}
```

без стрелочной функции все то же самое:

```
function PopupWithForm ({ active, setActive, name, id, title }) {...}
```

или

```
function PopupWithForm (props) {
 const { active, setActive, name, id, title } = props;
...
}
```